# Authentication is required. Sign in with your Google Account

Tags: android, google-play

Today I added my first application to play google stores. Send your application went smoothly. The application was in store. But as I want to download this application pops up an alert: `Authentication is required. Sign in with your Google Account.` I might also add that I am logged into your Google account, and checking whether the application runs on several other phones. But unfortunately, the situation repeated itself. Very Please help.

Comment: I have the same problem, it is past 20 hours since my application is published in the market but noone can download it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and how to fix it is very simple just go to your apps description and update it with anything I just added  one word clicked update and an hour later worked perfectly

Comment: As I'm not sure what the cause was I'm not sure if this is coincidental, but I tried this and <15mins later my app is now available to my alpha testers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment as I am a new user.
But it seems its an issue with the Google Play, as every one is facing the same issue.
I got 7 apps uploaded yesterday and none of them are working. I have retried to upload again today, and waiting to see the outcome.

Let me know if your apps are working fine now or if any updates on this.