# Authentication required for Google Play published app

Tags: android, google-play, phonegap-build

I have **just** published a pretty simple application in Google Play, built using Phonegap Build (Adobe's cloud service).

The app is being listed in Google Play but it says "This app is incompatible with all of your devices". If I try to install it, it pops up an error saying "Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account" and nothing happens.

I tried installing it in multiple devices, each with a different Google Account. Could it be that the app is not yet available for download or is there a configuration problem on my end?

Here is the link to the app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartcode.willitrain

Comment: Same issue for me (try trikita.quilt package ID), published a few hours ago, and I believe the same issue is also described in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309221/authentication-is-required-sign-in-with-your-google-account 
Your app is incompatible with all my devices, too, and I can't download it from the phone's Play Store apk.

Comment: Also, same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320728/this-app-is-incompatible-with-your-device-in-play-storegalaxy-s5-only-read-pho
All the questions I linked were posted a few hours ago, so it must be something broken at Google Play.

Comment: So maybe we just have to wait a little bit?

Comment: Probably so. But it never happened to the apps I posted in the past - they all appeared in a couple of hours and just worked.
Btw, I also just posted a question to Google Play support team just in case.

Comment: On Google Play forum the authentication issue has been reported since early March: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/play/authentication%7Csort:relevance

Comment: Please keep me posted if you have any progress with this, as I will too. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem and how to fix it is very simple just go to your apps description and update it with anything I just added  one word clicked update and an hour later worked perfectly

Comment: It works for me. Just need add a word -> Submit update -> DONE.

Answer (score 1):

I found what caused the problem in Google Play. In the publishing console and specifically in the "Services & APIs" menu, initially I had entered my GCM sender ID (my app sends push notifications). I thought this would be a nice feature, as it said it would maintain usage stats for me.

I don't know why this doesn't work, but when I removed my sender ID, it worked **instantly** and now everyone can download the app.

Comment: Ha. I'm not using GCM at all, but I tried editing game description today (just replaced one word with a synonym) and got the app working on all devices immediately! So Google Play was broken yesterday, but Google hasn't informed us about it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

i have this same problem put i think that i found solution (and trouble maker). Google Play change content rating and have a new one. Go to Store Listing and find "New content rating" there will be a link to new formula. I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Still no information has been sent by Google but this problem just happened again for me. Updating app desc fixed for me as well.