# Google Play Store new content rating

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app with new Google content rating and I can't install this app from store.

I have got error that I need authorization and I should sign in into google account.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, when I try to download from browser it says that "This app is incompatible with your device", and when I try to download from the phone it asks me to sign in. However I did not use the new ranking system, I just rated it manually without filling out a survey. The app link is here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pjAppDevelopment.pipes

Comment: I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323273/authentication-required-for-google-play-published-app All you need to do is update your app description by one word, and that somehow gets the Google servers to refresh and fix the bug. It worked instantly for me.